# ng table with server data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I tried to intialize ng table with server data. But it doesn't load the data in the table.

However I can able to see the ajax call is successful in console. After ajax call I see multiple table row line without data.

Any Idea what am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
 var tableAp = angular.module('tableApp', ["ngTable"]);
 tableAp.controller('testTable', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {    
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        getData: function(params) {
            $http.get('http://localhost/data.php')
                .success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    params.total(data.inlineCount);
                    return data;
                    //console.log(data);

                });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="tableApp">
<div ng-controller="testTable">
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td>
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td>
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please give the returned JSON data here?

Comment: Hi @Md.Rahman this is the example data with same structure. `[{"name":"name1","age":1},{"name":"name2","age":2},{"name":"name3","age":3}
,{"name":"name4","age":4},{"name":"name5","age":5},{"name":"name6","age":6},{"name":"name7","age":7}
,{"name":"name8","age":8}]` I see in console

Answer (score 0):

You use `ng-repeat="user in $data">` in your html, but I can't find where you define the `$data` in your controller.

Furthermore it seems like you are try to inject a custom service named `NgTableParams` in your controller. You don't need to "create an Object" of this. It is a singelton.

Comment: I have a doubt on this too. But in the documentation I too don't see any data in the controller Here is the [URL](http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-managed-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [DEMO LINK HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/ILVzD27m58NYnSFg5HEh?p=preview)

Please use **ngTableParams** instead of **NgTableParams**.
And update your script

```
<script>
 var tableAp = angular.module('tableApp', ["ngTable"]);
 tableAp.controller('testTable', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {  
      $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
          { page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
          },
          {
                getData: function($defer,params) { // --- add $defer
                    $http.get('http://localhost/data.php')
                        .success(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            params.total(data.inlineCount);
                            $defer.resolve(data); // ---- add this

                        });
                }
            });
});
</script>
```

Also update html by adding closing table tag

```
<body ng-app="tableApp">
<div ng-controller="testTable">
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td>
            {{user.name}}</td>
        <td>
            {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working fine in plunkr. However if I try $defer in my example. It throws error as `Error: params is undefined`

Comment: i suspect there is no more $defer in new ng-table's getData(), only getData(params).